# SQL Server - T-SQL UNION ALL + PIVOT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way that I can PIVOT the following SQL Query so I can retain the 3 different column names in each individual query as 1 row. At the moment it gives me the results as 3 rows under 1 column name from the first query.

```
SELECT COUNT(sdo.Id) AS [TotalNew] FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder] sdo WHERE sdo.[CampaignId]=@p0 AND sdo.[CreatedOn] >= 
(
   SELECT CAST(MAX(sdo.[CreatedOn]) AS DATE) FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder] sdo WHERE sdo.[CampaignId]=@p0
)
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(sdo.Id) AS [TotalNewSuccess] FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder] sdo 
INNER JOIN [Collections] c ON c.[DebitOrderId]=sdo.[Id]
WHERE sdo.[CampaignId]=@p0 AND sdo.[CreatedOn] >= 
(
   SELECT CAST(MAX(sdo.[CreatedOn]) AS DATE) FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder] sdo WHERE sdo.[CampaignId]=@p0
) AND c.TxnStatus='S'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(sdo.Id) AS [TotalNewFailed] FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder] sdo 
INNER JOIN [Collections] c ON c.[DebitOrderId]=sdo.[Id]
WHERE sdo.[CampaignId]=@p0 AND sdo.[CreatedOn] >= 
(
   SELECT CAST(MAX(sdo.[CreatedOn]) AS DATE) FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder] sdo WHERE sdo.[CampaignId]=@p0
) AND c.TxnStatus='U'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the query to be the one below.

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(*) AS [TotalNew]
,sum(case when c.TxnStatus='S' then 1 else 0 end) as [TotalNewSuccess]
,sum(case when c.TxnStatus='U' then 1 else 0 end) as [TotalNewFailed]
FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder] sdo 
INNER JOIN [Collections] c ON c.[DebitOrderId]=sdo.[Id]
WHERE sdo.[CampaignId]=@p0 
AND sdo.[CreatedOn] >= 
(
 SELECT CAST(MAX([CreatedOn]) AS DATE) 
 FROM [SubscriberDebitOrder]
 WHERE [CampaignId] = @p0
)
```

Comment: Thanks @vkp, I wish I can explain this beautiful query of yours so I can reuse it. But for this particular requirement, it simply worked. Thanks again...

Comment: Using `COUNT(CASE c.TxnStatus WHEN 'S' THEN 1 END) AS [TotalNewSuccess]` describes the use better... and will be faster in large datasets.

Comment: @vkp, for some reason [TotalNew] seems to be giving me more results than expected. It seems to be giving me exactly [TotalNew] + [TotalNewFailed]. Would you be able to know why?

Comment: @MatthewWhited, thanks for the tip. Check my comment above in case you know what could be wrong with the answer please...?

Comment: i think the table only has statuses S and U. And the totalnew column is the count of all the rows in the joined resultset. What is your expected result? i can help if you add more detail.

Comment: Change `TotalNew` to `COUNT(DISTINCT c."Unique ID")`.  With the joins your total count may be inflated.  If you also have duplicate issues on the `TotalNewSuccess/TotalNewFailed` change the `THEN` to the same unique id and add the DISTINCT clause to the COUNT.

Comment: Ok I changed to COUNT(DISTINCT sdo.Id) AS [TotalNew] and SQL Server hangs on "Executing query..."
The concept is that a SubscriberDebitOrder might have MANY Collections. So when I remove the INNER JOIN and only get the results for TotalNew then it's accurate. When I include the INNER JOIN then I get more results. I'm still waiting for 5 minutes for the DISTINCT to return results. Is it supposed to be that slow?

Comment: I feel like `having sdo.[CreatedOn] = max(sdo.[CreatedOn])` should work

Comment: Ok for now I've done an over-kill until I find a better solution:

(COUNT(sdo.Id)-COUNT(CASE c.TxnStatus WHEN 'U' THEN 1 END)) AS [TotalNew]